# Near-impossible puzzle for Christmas

Tags: puzzle-creation

I'm going to setup a puzzle contest for my family and friends for Christmas. The puzzles are hard, but doable in 1-2 hours (along the lines of Sudoku, Crosswords and Logic Tables puzzles).

However, I have all of them ready, except for **one**. I would like to propose for one of them (randomly chosen) a **near-impossible to solve puzzle**. By near-impossible I mean:

- It has a solution;
- The solution is very hard to find, and impossible to solve in 1-2 hours for an intelligent person with access to the Internet and a computer;
- The puzzle does not seem to be very hard (as I said before, something that appears to be solvable with some effort);
- He/She will get the prize if stating that the puzzle is impossible to solve with the time and resources given to them.

Could you help with that? I will accept the most original puzzle satisfying these constraints <s>in the next 24 hours</s>. **EDIT: Sorry guys, I got two answers that do not satisfy all constraints (both are far from near-impossible), so I'm going to leave the question open.**

PS: Based on [Ideas on puzzles for a scientific event](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/36866/ideas-on-puzzles-for-a-scientific-event), I came to the conclusion that this question is not off-topic (requesting puzzles).

Comment: Check out [Linked Word Squares](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/36044/linked-word-squares), right here on this site, an [excellent](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/5557/18129) fill-in-words puzzle that is fun well before it has been completed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of taking "nearly impossible" puzzle, which can frustrate easily, I would suggest "open optimization problem". I.e. a task with many solutions, which can be ordered from worst to best. So everyone can enjoy it and find a solution, while it is still competitive.

For example:

[Fastest way to collect an arbitrary army](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/548/fastest-way-to-collect-an-arbitrary-army)

[Find a straight tunnel](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11972/find-a-straight-tunnel)

[Two spies throwing stones into a river](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/625/two-spies-throwing-stones-into-a-river)

[Knights and jokers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/593/knights-and-jokers)

[Maximize the number of paths](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38398/maximize-the-number-of-paths)

Or may be you can find something better with ["optimization" tag](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization).

Answer (score 4):

1) What is the lowest number of cuts in a circle do you need to get 622 pieces? (They don't have to be all the same size and the cuts can be randomly placed)
It didn't take 1-2 hours to solve but i had fun solving it :-)

2) Take the sum of 17 successive numbers. Like starting at 55 for example: $55+56+57+58...$ 17 times. Is this sum ALWAYS and I mean ALWAYS divisible by one of the 17 numbers? If or if not justify your answer.
This is also a very mathematical problem but this is everything what comes to my mind right now.

Hope you get the answers not too fast and enjoy my puzzles. Cheers :)

Comment: I don't think the second is near-impossible. If the middle of those 17 numbers is N then their average is also N, so the sum is 17N, so the sum is always a multiple of the middle number. Am I missing something? (The same thing works if you replace 17 with any other odd number.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan yes thats true! I guess that one was to easy

Comment: Is the answer to the first question 35 cuts?

Comment: Both are actually fairly easy, because the [Lazy carterer's sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_caterer's_sequence) will say that (n^2+n+2)/2 = total cuts, and you just have to solve an equation after that